# Logback-test.xml configuration is producing two log files instead of one?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

When I stop running my `spring-boot` application there are **two** log files produced rather than **one** (one is expected).

What is wrong in my `Logback-test.xml` file below that may be causing this?

**logback-test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="myTimestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss.SSS"/>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}  - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>C:\path\to\my\file\myLog-${myTimestamp}.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>myLog.%i{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS}}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.my.package" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The two files being created are e.g.:

```
myLog-2016-04-22_15-47-30.126.log

and

myLog-2016-04-22_15-47-30.922.log
```

Comment: is the filename pattern the same?

Comment: please see edit thanks

Comment: can you try replacing the rolling file appender with a normal `FileAppender`

Comment: Ok what difference is this?

Comment: just trying to narrow down the source of this. since the pattern is the same on both files

Comment: Can you give us Logback's output in your STDOUT when running with `<configuration debug="true">` http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The timestamp is generated when the configuration is parsed. Since Spring Boot reinitializes logback once during startup, two different timestamps are generated and therefore the two files.

You can use a `timeReferene="contextBirth"` in your config to get a constant timestamp. Since the `LoggerContext` isn't destroyed, just resetted this should work:

```
<timestamp key="myTimestamp" timeReference="contextBirth" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss.SSS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not really following what you say the solution it?

Answer (score 3):

How does your `logging.config` property look? You problem may be the [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332540/3166303) (or the property missing from your properties file). E.g. should look something like this:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-test.xml
```

in `application-test.properties`.

The other possibility might be that you have two active profiles. E.g. your `test` profile and the `default` one. In that case, you can get around it with conditional configuration in logback.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29430074/1837047) for more details. Also, see the last comment on that answer. spring boot 1.3 includes some new features around handling multiple profiles with logback:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logback-extensions

Comment: I do not currently have this logging.config property? Do I need it?

Comment: if you are setting profile-specific logging config, then I think so, yes. But its possible boot can figure this out on its own though, not 100% sure. Still can't hurt to be explicit though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably related to this line:

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```

[This version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.3.x/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml) of the included files is including to others and one of [them have a file appender](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.3.x/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml). Since you are defining your own appenders (file and console), you probably don't need to include the Spring Boot base file.

Comment: No I commented that out but stil got 2 log files?

Comment: Hum, I saw that you are using milliseconds to define the filename. Maybe it could be a bug at logback initialization. What if you change the pattern to not use milliseconds?

Comment: Also, which version of logback are you using?

Comment: Also not working unfortunately, I removed the miliseconds but I still get 2 log files: One is one second older than the other

Comment: Did you tried to add `<configuration debug="true">` as suggested by @GuiSim?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender"">

    <file>C:\path\to\my\file\myLog-${myTimestamp}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

<!--
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>myLog.%i{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS}}.log</FileNamePattern>
        <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
        <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
-->
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>50MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

</appender>
```

Comment: No I get the error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException-no applicable action for [triggeringPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][triggeringPolicy]]

Comment: Sorry, there is an extra double quote at the end of the first line. Hoping so you removed it and tried.