# Can I get timestamp into spring boot log file name w/out separate config file?

Tags: spring-boot

Is there some simple placeholder I can use in the application.properties, something like:

```
logging.file=myApplication-${timestamp}.log
```

without any additional xml files or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't configure it without an additional logging configuration file specific to the logging framework itself (log4j, logback, ...). This is what [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) mentions:

> To configure the more **fine-grained settings** of a logging system you need to use the **native configuration** format supported by the `LoggingSystem` in question.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796280/1915448) explains how you could configure this for Logback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on unix based machine you can do so in shell script.

`--logging.file=application-"$(date '+%Y-%m-%d:%H:::%M')".log`

or

`#!/bin/sh:
append_date = "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d:%H:::%M')"
java -jar spring-application.jar --logging.file=application-$append_date .log`